# Is it possible to build a stand-alone metro app (no windows store)?

Tags: microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I see that metro apps were rebranded either "windows 8 apps" or "windows store apps".

Is there a term for that style of full-screen-app independent of the workflow of publishing through their store? Can you build a windows 8 app that can be installed directly?

Answer (score 4):

There are 3-ways to get a "Windows 8 Store" Application on a system (that is to say, deploy a APPX package)

- From the store
- Unlocking the machine by acquiring a developer license using Visual Studio or the Powershell Commandlet
- Using the side loading license available when you are using the "Enterprise" SKU.

There are no other ways to get an apps package deployed.

That stated, **traditional** windows applications are still able to be deployed on x64 and x86 machines. ARM devices (Windows RT) cannot run anything except Windows 8 Store applications.

Comment: And to clarify, a "Windows 8 Store" application and what used to be called a "Metro Style Application" are the same thing? To write an app of that style for our business and deploy it internally or to clients would require an Enterprise sku of Visual Studio. Correct?

Comment: Enterprise sku of *Windows 8*. You only need the express sku of VS.

Comment: Actually, according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx, there should be a 4th way using an obscure product key "admins" can acquire somewhere. Problem is that sideloading must be enabled. One can achieve that using a developer license, but this must be renewed regularly. Besides this trick would not be the proper way to deploy a Windows Store app so businesses.

Comment: No wonder nobody develops their apps. If you don't want to buy visual studio you are not able to build and deploy for testing.